# Determining Laurent series $f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-2)(z-3)}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have a question about determining the Laurent series of the function

$f(z)=\frac{1}{(z-2)(z-3)}$.

I have determined the three rings:
$|z|<2$,
$2<|z|<3$ and $|z|>3$.
I know that in the first ring f(z) is analytic and in the second ring not, but why?
I thought they both have no singularities so the function is analytic there..

Comment: Why do you say the function is not analytic in the annulus $2<|z|<3$?

Comment: The function $f$ is analytic in the second ring.  But the Laurent series centered at zero (which you didn't say) has negative as well as positive terms.  These are not contradictory.

Comment: I'd second @GEdgar, and perhaps add that (as you probably know) an analytic (using the terms you've used, although this is precisely where I'd prefer a-priori calling it holomporphic) function in a disc has a representation there as a power series about the center. Also, perhaps you'd find it useful to develop the Laurent series for each of the simple poles separately.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, we should find the partial fraction decomposition of $f(z)$ then get

$$f(z) =\frac{1}{z-3} - \frac{1}{z-2}.$$

Now, for first given region 
$|z|<2$ we have $\dfrac{|z|}{2} < 1$ and hence obviously $\dfrac{|z|}{3} < 1$
 so we can expand $\left(1-\dfrac{z}{3}\right)^{-1}$ and also $\left(1-\dfrac{z}{2}\right)^{-1}$ binomially.

In second region, $|z|<3$ and $|z|>2$. Hence $\dfrac{|z|}{3}<1$ and $\dfrac{2}{|z|}<1$ so we expand $\left(1-\dfrac{z}{3}\right)^{-1}$ & $\left(1-\dfrac{2}{z}\right)^{-1}$ binomially

In third region, $|z|>3$, $\dfrac{3}{|z|}<1$ & obeviously $|z|>2$ hence $\dfrac{2}{z}<1$ so we expand  $\left(1-\dfrac{3}{z}\right)^{-1}$ and $\left(1-\dfrac{2}{z}\right)^{-1}$ binomially.

NOTE THAT
$\left(1-x\right)^{-1}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots$ for $|x|<1$

This is the best way to get Laurent's expansion of $f(z).$ If I solve your problem please leave a comment.

Comment: You can't leave the second term as it is. Otherwise it's not a Laurent series centered at $0$.

Comment: sorry i just noticed that, i hope now u will setisfy.take a look of edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach to finding the Laurent Series for simple rational functions is to make use of the geometric series expansion:

$$\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^\infty w^n = \dfrac{1}{1-w}, \text{where } |w| < 1$$

Depending on which region you are in, you'll have a different $w$. $w$ is always chosen so that it is less than $1$ in the region.

Normally, Laurent series expansions are constructed with the singular point at the center of the expansion. The user 123 wrote a nice exposition writing an expansion centered at $0$, but that's not what one would normally do.

If you choose $2$ as the center, you can write expansions in the regions

$|z-2| < 1$ and $|z-2| > 1$. (Do you see why?)

In either case we'd like to expand with $|z-2|$.

**Region 1: $|z-2|<1$**

In the first region, you would use $w = z-2$. More generally, for $|z-a|<r$, you'd use $w=\frac{z-a}{r}$.

$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{(z-2)(z-3)}$

Here, $(z-2)$ is just fine. We need to change $(z-3)$. This is done by

$$\dfrac{1}{z-3} = \dfrac{1}{(z-2)-1} = -\dfrac{1}{1-(z-2)} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-2)^n$$

And so,

$$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{(z-2)(z-3)} = -\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-2)^{n-1}$$

**Region 2: $|z-2|>1$**

Here, we will use $w = \dfrac{1}{z-2}$. More generally, for $|z-a|<r$, you would use $w = \frac{r}{z-a}$.

Again, we only need to take care of the $z-3$ factor. The computation is very similar to what was done for region 1:

$$\dfrac{1}{z-3} = \dfrac{1}{(z-2)-1} = \dfrac{1}{(z-2)(1-\frac{1}{z-2})} = \dfrac{1}{z-2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-2)^{-n}$$

And so,

$$f(z) = \dfrac{1}{(z-2)(z-3)} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (z-2)^{-n-2}$$

Now that you've seen how it is done at $z=2$, you should try and see if you can write the Laurent Series expansions at $z=3$, and maybe other places too.