# Determining the Laurent Series

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need to determine the Laurent series of this function:
$$\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+5)}$$ Inside the annulus: $$\left\{z\,|\,1<|z-2|<6\right\}$$ Any help appreciated.

Comment: Start with partial fraction decomposition...

Comment: I obtained 1/6(1/(z-1)-1/(z+5)), whats next?

Comment: Now you have to use geometric series for both of them to "make" your fractions. Have you studied geometric series? Here is a link of a similar problem: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/644939/determining-laurent-series-fz-frac1z-2z-3?rq=1

Comment: Actually, here I'm a bit stuck.

Comment: your inner radius for the annulus is 2???

Comment: I haven't written anything out incorrectly. That's the question I was given. I just wanted to better understand how to solve it.

Comment: do you mean inside the annulus $1<|z-2|<6$ ?

Comment: Oh dear. I did write it incorrectly!

Comment: @user975 Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I just want to give you the best answer I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using partial fraction expansion, we can write

$$\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+5)}=\frac{1/6}{z-1}-\frac{1/6}{z+5}$$

We seek a series about the center of the annulus $z=2$.  To that end,

$$\begin{align}
-\frac{1/6}{z+5}&=\frac16 \frac{1}{(z-2)+7}\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{42}\frac{1}{1+\frac{z-1}{7}}\\\\
&=-\frac{1}{42} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left(\frac{z-2}{7}\right)^n
\end{align}$$

which converges within the entire annulus.  We also can write

$$\begin{align}
\frac{1/6}{z-1}&=\frac16 \frac{1}{(z-2)+1}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{6}\frac{1/(z-2)}{1+(z-2)^{-1}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{6} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}(z-2)^{-n}
\end{align}$$

which converges for $|z-2|>1$, which completely covers the annulus.  Thus, the appropriate Laurent series is

$$\frac{1}{(z-1)(z+5)}=\frac{1}{6} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}(z-2)^{-n}-\frac{1}{42} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (-1)^n\left(\frac{z-2}{7}\right)^n$$

Comment: Dr.MV thank you for the solution

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is just a set up: $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+.....$,then
$\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4-.....$ then $\frac{1}{1+x/5}=\frac{5}{5+x}=1-(x/5)+(x/5)^2-(x/5)^3+(x/5)^4-.....$ Now divide by 5 to get $\frac{1}{5+x}=1/5-(x/5)/5+(x/5)^2/5-(x/5)^3/5+...$ And then integrate. Can you now work out the details?

Comment: Thank you Imran. I'm going to have a go.

Comment: @imranfat There might be a typos in the lines that both precede and succeed the note "Now divide by 5 to get."

Comment: @Dr.MV Could you be more specific? I can't find it

Comment: @imranfat  No worry. I might need glasses.  Everything is fine.  But I believe that only 1 Laurent series was requested.  And so, one should expand about $z=2$ to ensure that both series cover the annulus.  Or perhaps, you were only giving a general scheme.

Comment: @Dr.MV Yes, my answer was not complete (far from it) I was hoping to get the OP on the right track.